# sessionStorage not saving or not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to (re)fill a text area using [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) but this seems not to be working.

I have a dropdown which when used also fills the content from the "title" tag into a text area. The drop-down forces the page to reload and thus will empty the text area again. For this I am trying to use sessionStorage to refill the text area again. But something's going wrong.

When I use the drop-down and after that go one page back in the browser, I see the text area is filled. But if I then refresh that page the text area is empty again. So this leads me to think that the text area is not being saved or loaded by sessionStorage.

Please [look here](http://www.photographycoursetour.com/amsterdam-one-day-photo-course-beginners.html) and use the drop down named "test". The text area is right next to it.

Can anyone help, please?

My code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="currency select" title="Currency Selector">
    <select name="currency" id="currencyList" onchange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"  value="GO">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" none="">TEST</option> 
        <option value="/session/currency/usd/" title="US Dollar">USD</option>
        <option value="/session/currency/eur/" title="EURO">EUR</option>
    </select>

    <textarea id="showTitle"></textarea>

</form>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('change','#currencyList',function()
    {
       var result = $("option:selected",this).attr('title');
       $("#showTitle").text(result);
    }

  // Get the text field that we're going to track
var field = document.getElementById("showTitle");

// See if we have an autosave value
// (this will only happen if the page is accidentally refreshed)
if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave")) {
  // Restore the contents of the text field
  field.value = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");
}

  // Listen for changes in the text field
field.addEventListener("change", function() {
  // And save the results into the session storage object
  sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", field.value);

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: there's an error on that page, and you are missing a `)` here....

Answer (score 0):

You should close the `$(document).on('change'..){` with `});`.

Also try to add this, to check if the browser allows localStorage:

```
//At the beggining
if(!supportsHTML5Storage()) { return false; //or alert() }


/**
 * function that checks if the browser supports HTML5
 * local storage
 *
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function supportsHTML5Storage() {
    try {
        return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've received an answer, this is the working code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="currency select" title="Currency Selector">
    <select name="currency" id="currencyList" onchange="window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"  value="GO">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" none="">TEST</option> 
        <option value="/session/currency/usd/" title="US Dollar">USD</option>
        <option value="/session/currency/eur/" title="EURO">EUR</option>
    </select>

    <textarea id="showTitle"></textarea>

</form>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    var field = document.getElementById("showTitle");


    // See if we have an autosave value
    // (this will only happen if the page is accidentally refreshed)
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("autosave")) {
    // Restore the contents of the text field
        field.value = sessionStorage.getItem("autosave");
    }

    // Listen for changes in the text field
    field.addEventListener("input", function() {
        // And save the results into the session storage object
        sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", this.value);
    });

   $(document).on('change','#currencyList',function(){
        //get text
       var result = $("option:selected",this).attr('title');
       //set field
       $(field).val(result);
       //set session storage item
        sessionStorage.setItem("autosave", result);
        //redirect
       //window.document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    });

   });

</script>
</body>
```